# How to combine multiple mysql tables data resultset for geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, geotools

I need to extract data from multiple tables, choose whether to remove duplication or add up according to the business rules.

I have read some related GeoTools documents, such as ContentDataStore. But all I need is to assemble my own result set. Is there a simpler way that I can implement certain methods of class? It's just the data assembly or can you give me more tutorials or some custom examples?

Comment: could you make it into a view?

Comment: thanks lan. but i can't do it with the sql view as its only support select clauses. as i have to parse the feature collection to re-combine datas, i first thought is to use a mysql function or procedure to do it, but seems GS doesn't support. the logics for examples is, i have table A with three records(r1,r2,r3), while table B also have three records but with newer r1, deleted r2 , and r4. So the output resultset is records newer r1, r3, r4. how should i do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of it you are going to need a custom datastore, while you could start from a `ContentDataStore` and implement everything you need, it might be easier if you extended [`MySQLJDBCDataStore`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-mysql/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/mysql).

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can define a custom view using Parameterizing SQL Views http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html

Comment: as sql view can only support select. i shall have some data combine logics.a stored procedure might be a solution but GS donot support it.any other clues?